# Como hacer un cambio masivo de un parametro en una lista con LinQ

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una lista de usuarios:

```
var usuarios = new List<Usuario>();

usuarios.Add(
nombre: "Alejandro",
apellido: "Ladner",
edad: 21);

usuarios.Add(
nombre: "Ivan",
apellido: "Pepe",
edad: 25);


usuarios.Add(
nombre: "Martin",
apellido: "Pamflin",
edad: 40);
```

Hay alguna manera con linq de setearle la edad en 30 a TODOS los usuarios en la lista?

Lo que intento hacer con LinQ es esto:

```
foreach(var item in usuarios)
{
    item.Edad = 30;
}
```

Comment: ¿Te da algún error ese código?

Comment: no, ninguno, solo que lo quiero hacer con linq

Comment: Te sugiero leer la documentación de Linq, a veces por querer que el código se vea "pro", terminan generando mayor consumo de memoria, cpu. Mira esta respuesta en SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755487/3613462 tiene lo que estás buscando, por favor, ignora la idea de realizar lo que tiene la pregunta aceptada, un `select` debería usarse para 1 de 2: o bien seleccionar algunos campos y ya, o bien transformar los datos hacia otra clase `(select new Nuevaclase)`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres cambiar la edad de todos los Items con Linq puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
usuarios.ForEach(a=>a.Edad=30);
```

Si lo que quieres es actualizar masivamente un campo en una Tabla usando Entity Framework, ahora en la versión 7 existe la función `ExecuteUpdate` y su similar asíncrono `ExecuteUpdateAsync`

```
db.usuarios.ExecuteUpdateAsync(a=>a.SetProperty(b=>b.Edad,b=>30));
```